# regex for inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the function

```
function getChecked(button, form)
{
    var name;
    for (i = 0; i < document.forms['CheckForm'].list.length; i++) {
        name = "Check" + (i + 0);
        if (document.forms['CheckForm'].list[i].checked == true) {
            if (name == "Check0")
                form.Check0.value = "2337667";
            else if (name == "Check1")
                form.Check1.value = "2335765";
            else if (name == "Check2")
                form.Check2.value = "2332651";
            else if (name == "Check3")
                form.Check3.value = "2328582";
        }
```

How to write a regex to get the value for the values after `form.check0.value` by itself and if possible the values for `form.check0.value` and `form.check1.value` and etc.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha i am trying to get an regex expresssion to match the values inside this function

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to match? Is there a pattern?

Comment: these numbers here 2337667,2335765,2332651 ect... i need an array of the numbers

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://codepad.viper-7.com/dIC83b ?

Comment: @DaveRandom yes your answer is perfect!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this regex:

```
/\d{2,}/g
```

Example:

```
var s = 'function getChecked(button, form){\n    var name;\n    for (i = 0; i < document.forms["CheckForm"].list.length; i++) {\n        name = "Check" + (i + 0);\n        if (document.forms["CheckForm"].list[i].checked == true) {\n            if (name == "Check0")\n                form.Check0.value = "2337667";\n            else if (name == "Check1")\n                form.Check1.value = "2335765";\n            else if (name == "Check2")\n                form.Check2.value = "2332651";\n            else if (name == "Check3")\n                form.Check3.value = "2328582";\n        }\n    }\n}';
console.log(s.match(/\d{2,}/g));
```

Output:

```
["2337667", "2335765", "2332651", "2328582"];
```

As for that PHP sample provided by @Daverandom, that can be shortened significantly:

```php
preg_match_all('/\d{2,}/', $str, $matches); // Get all numbers that are at least 2 characters long.
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**[As seen in this paste](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fm6DUg)**